# How to remove Dynamic data validation error

Tags: vba

My code dynamically assigns validations from a list to a particular range of data. But an error is occurring in the same. All elements of the list are assigned to row1 but all elements minus the top element of the list are assigned to row2 and similarly, for row3 all elements minus the top two elements of the list are assigned and so on. Please see the images for a better understanding of my problem

```
With sht.Range("C2:C" & LastRow1).Validation 'LastRow1 is the last row till which validations have to be assigned
    .delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=DropDown!C2:C" & LastRowS 'LastRowS is the last row of the list from which validations will be assigned
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Value not present in drop down."
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

[image: LIST]
[image: ROW1]
[image: ROW2]

Comment: Use `"=DropDown!$C$2:$C$" & LastRowS` as formula

Comment: @Vincent G Thanks for the help :)